# Javascript file not loaded after redirect?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app and noticed that my custom JavaScript file is not being loaded after a redirect.  I include script file at the bottom of the _layout.cshtml page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>

  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

<script src="js/CustomScripts.js"></script>  @* NOT LOADED AFTER REDIRECT PAGE IS LOADED *@
```

My controller

```
public IActionResult Edit(EnrollmentsModel enrollmentsModel)
{
  var enrollment = _smcdService.GetEnrollmentModel(nCustId, nAccId, nMeterId, nSMCDId);

  return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Enrollment", enrollment);
}
```

My Edit page display the correct data but the 'CustomScripts.js' file isn't loaded.  My other web pages load the Javascript file but they are not redirected.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, for one thing, the `script` element comes after the `</html>`, which is not valid HTML. Why not includeit after `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I made the change but still get the same results.

Comment: Is the page you're redirecting to perhaps at a different level than the others? (e.g., the URL is `/Edit/Enrollment` whereas the others are like `/Edit`). I see you're using a relative url to your script `src="js/CustomScripts.js"` as opposed to a app-relative one `src="~/js/CustomScripts.js"`.

Comment: Change `<script src="js/..."` to `<script src="~/js/..."`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the reference url of your script begins with '~'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>

  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
  <script src="~/js/CustomScripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```